# how to display records from my sql database into jquery datatable plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, ajax

how to display records from my sql database into jquery datatable plugin...
here is my code client side code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#show").click(function () {
            $("#UpdatePanel").html("<div style='text-align:center; background-color:yellow; border:1px solid red; padding:3px; width:200px'>Please Wait...</div>");

            var URL = "~/Default.aspx/Display";
            $.ajax({
                url : URL,
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "json",
                Contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data :"{}",
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#updatepanel").text(msg.d);
                }})
        })
    });
</script>
```

here is my server side code

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Det display()
{
    string conn = "Data Source=waheed-pc\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Mydatabase;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    try
    {
        Det details = new Det();   

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Mytable", con);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return details;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        con.Close();
        throw;
    }


}
public class Det
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public int Contactno { get; set; }
}
```

please help me to solve this problem 
if u have another method to display my records from my database from server side using asp.net c# ,jquery , ajax,json at client side

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ExecuteReader()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` when you are using `SELECT` Query.

Try This: change your `try` block as below:

```
try
{
Det details = Det();   
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ID,Name,Job,ContactNo From Mytable", con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
while(reader.Read())
{
  details.ID=reader["ID"].ToString();
  details.Name=reader["Name"].ToString();
  details.Job=reader["Job"].ToString();
  details.ContactNo=reader["ContactNo"].ToString();
}

con.Close();
return details;
}
```

**NOTE:** I have change your `SELECT` query for more convenience you can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

but my intellisence is not showing the bold faces statment
details.ID = **details.reader**["ID"].tostring();

Comment: Sorry it should be `details.ID = reader["ID"].tostring();` check my edited answer